# Sum the JSON Data and Display in the Required Field

Tags: android, json, sum, display

I am using ListView,inside listView i have used linearLayout to populate the Courses Data through JSON.I want to Display the **Total sum of the Courses MarksObtained** through the JSON data.I am not Able to add the Data from the JSON and to Display in the Specific Field.

**StudentProgressReportAdapter**

```
public class StudentProgressReportAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LinearLayout coursesViewDynamic;

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<StudentProgressReportPojo> student_list_courses;


    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";

    public StudentProgressReportAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<StudentProgressReportPojo> student_list_courses) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.student_list_courses = student_list_courses;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        System.out.println(student_list_courses.size());
        return student_list_courses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return student_list_courses.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int postion, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final StudentProgressReportAdapter.Holder viewHolder;


        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_progress_report, parent, false);


            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new StudentProgressReportAdapter.Holder();

            viewHolder.student_progress_report_termdenoter = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_term_denoter);
            viewHolder.student_progress_report_subjectTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_progressreport_subject_total);



            //added code
            viewHolder.coursesLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.courses_layout);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            viewHolder = (StudentProgressReportAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        // Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + postion + " getFeeDescription" + student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription());
        // Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + postion + " getAmount" + student_list.get(postion).getAmount());


        viewHolder.student_progress_report_termdenoter.setText(student_list_courses.get(postion).getTermDenoter());
        viewHolder.student_progress_report_subjectTotal.setText(Integer.toString(student_list_courses.get(postion).getSubjectTotal()));


        // viewHolder.receiptLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        //added code

        //  Fee fee=new Fee();
        //   JSONArray x=fee.jArray1;


        viewHolder.coursesLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < student_list_courses.get(postion).getCourses().size(); i++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //   reciptViewDynamic = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bil_info, null);


            coursesViewDynamic = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_progress_report_courses_listitem, parent, false);


            //  TextView textView = (TextView) coursesViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_progressreport_subject_coursename);
            //  textView.setText(student_list_courses.get(postion).getCourses().get(i));
            viewHolder.student_progress_report_courses = (TextView) coursesViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_progressreport_subject_coursename);
            viewHolder.student_progress_report_courses.setText(student_list_courses.get(postion).getCourses().get(i));

            viewHolder.student_progress_report_subjectwise_obtainedmarks = (TextView) coursesViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_progressreport_subject_course_obtainedTerminalmarks);
            viewHolder.student_progress_report_subjectwise_obtainedmarks.setText(student_list_courses.get(postion).getStudentProgressReportMarksObtained().get(i));


            viewHolder.student_progress_report_subjectwise_fullmarks = (TextView) coursesViewDynamic.findViewById(R.id.student_progressreport_subject_terminal_fullmarks);
            viewHolder.student_progress_report_subjectwise_fullmarks.setText(student_list_courses.get(postion).getStudentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks().get(i));


            // Log.d(TAG, "@@ wrong information:" + student_list.get(postion).getFeeDescription());
            viewHolder.coursesLayout.addView(coursesViewDynamic);


        }

        // (reciptViewDynamic).removeView(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView student_progress_report_courses;
        TextView student_progress_report_termdenoter;
        TextView student_progress_report_subjectwise_obtainedmarks;
        TextView student_progress_report_subjectwise_fullmarks;
        TextView student_progress_report_subjectTotal;
        LinearLayout coursesLayout;
    }
}
```

**StudentProgressReportPojo**

```
public class StudentProgressReportPojo {


    String TermDenoter;
    String SubjectObtainedMarks;
    String TerminalFullMarks;
    Integer SubjectTotal;


    public StudentProgressReportPojo(String termDenoter, String subjectObtainedMarks, String terminalfullmarks, int total) {
        TermDenoter = termDenoter;
        SubjectObtainedMarks = subjectObtainedMarks;
        TerminalFullMarks = terminalfullmarks;
        SubjectTotal = total;

    }


    public StudentProgressReportPojo(Integer subjectTotal) {
        SubjectTotal = subjectTotal;
    }

    public String getTermDenoter() {
        return TermDenoter;
    }

    public Integer getSubjectTotal() {
        return SubjectTotal;
        //SubjectTotal = total;
    }

    public void setSubjectTotal(Integer subjectTotal) {
        SubjectTotal = subjectTotal;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> Courses = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getCourses() {
        return Courses;
    }


    public void setTermDenoter(String termDenoter) {
        TermDenoter = termDenoter;
    }

    public void addCourses(String courses) {
        Courses.add(courses);
    }


    //added
    public ArrayList<String> StudentProgressReportMarksObtained = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getStudentProgressReportMarksObtained() {
        return StudentProgressReportMarksObtained;
    }

    public void setStudentProgressReportMarksObtained(ArrayList<String> studentProgressReportMarksObtained) {
        StudentProgressReportMarksObtained = studentProgressReportMarksObtained;
    }

    public String getSubjectObtainedMarks() {
        return SubjectObtainedMarks;
    }

    public void addObtainedMarksSubjectWise(String studentProgressReportMarksObtained) {
        StudentProgressReportMarksObtained.add(studentProgressReportMarksObtained);

    }

    //added
    public ArrayList<String> StudentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getStudentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks() {
        return StudentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks;
    }

    public void addTerminalFullMarksSubjectWise(String studentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks) {
        StudentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks.add(studentProgressReportTerminalFullMarks);

    }

    public String getTerminalFullMarks() {
        return TerminalFullMarks;
    }
}
```

**getUserProgressData method**

```
public void getUserProgressData() {


        String URL = Navigation_URL + "?StdID=" + master_id;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            ArrayList<StudentProgressReportPojo> student_list_courses = new ArrayList<>();


                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            int x = 0;
                            //  studentFeeInformation = new StudentFeeInformation(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                System.out.println(i);
                                String course = jsonObject.getString("CourseName");
                                String examDescription = jsonObject.getString("examDescription");
                                String ObtainedMaks = jsonObject.getString("Marks");
                                //  System.out.println("the Obtained Marks is =" + ObtainedMaks);
                                x = (x + Integer.parseInt(ObtainedMaks));
                                String TerminalFullmarks = jsonObject.getString("Terminal_FM");
                                if (arrayList.contains(examDescription)) {
                                    student_list_courses.get(arrayList.indexOf(examDescription)).addCourses(course);
                                    student_list_courses.get(arrayList.indexOf(examDescription)).addObtainedMarksSubjectWise(ObtainedMaks);
                                    student_list_courses.get(arrayList.indexOf(examDescription)).addTerminalFullMarksSubjectWise(TerminalFullmarks);
                                    //student_list_courses.get(arrayList.indexOf(examDescription)).getSubjectTotal();


                                } else {


                                    StudentProgressReportPojo progressReportPojo = new StudentProgressReportPojo(examDescription, ObtainedMaks, TerminalFullmarks, x);
                                    progressReportPojo.addCourses(course);
                                    progressReportPojo.addObtainedMarksSubjectWise(ObtainedMaks);
                                    progressReportPojo.addTerminalFullMarksSubjectWise(TerminalFullmarks);
                                    arrayList.add(examDescription);
                                    student_list_courses.add(progressReportPojo);
                                    System.out.println("the Total number of x=" + x);


                                }


                                // System.out.println("the Sum=" + ObtainedMaks);


                                // I am going to add the information Within this Section.
                                // StudentProgressReportPojo StudentProgressReportPojo = new StudentProgressReportPojo(x);
                                //StudentProgressReportPojo.getSubjectTotal(x);
                                // StudentProgressReportPojo.setSubjectTotal(x);

                            }

                            System.out.println("Total Marks Obtainedis equal to" + x);
                            //StudentProgressReportPojo progressReportPojo1 = new StudentProgressReportPojo(x);
                            // progressReportPojo1.getSubjectTotal();


                            System.out.println("student_list size:" + student_list_courses.size());
                            StudentProgressReportAdapter studentProgressReportAdapter = new StudentProgressReportAdapter(getActivity(), student_list_courses);
                            listView.setAdapter(studentProgressReportAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("This is not good");
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(view.Fee.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return headers;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

**Json**

```
[
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5034,
    "Marks": 9,
    "Sno": 1082,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 6014,
    "CourseName": "Math",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "First Term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "transferRate": 18,
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  },
  {
    "CLASSNO": "1",
    "CLASS_ID": 2021,
    "CourseID": 5035,
    "Marks": 10.8,
    "Sno": 1083,
    "StdID": 95,
    "TermID": 6014,
    "CourseName": "English",
    "Terminal_FM": 100,
    "Terminal_PM": 40,
    "UT_FM": 50,
    "UT_PM": 20,
    "examDescription": "First Term",
    "type": "Terminal",
    "transferRate": 18,
    "NAME": "Calvin Patterson"
  }
]
```

> I suppose, i am able to add the subject marks but When i Display the
>   Sum on the TextView.The First Item ObtainedMarks is Displayed Rather
>   than that of the Total Sum.How can this issue be Solved?

Comment: Just to be clear: in your adapter you have list student_list_courses of StudentProgressReportPojo objects. In this class, there is field SubjectObtainedMarks which holds number, and you want to get sum of those numbers in whole list?

Comment: you are displaying `SubjectTotal` but you only set it on creating the pojo, you doesnt update the value if `examDescription`is present. right?

Comment: @thorin86 exactly

Comment: @fusselchen do i have to update? Where do i have to Udate i am confused

Comment: see thorins post, instead of updating the field on parsing, you can build the sum on filling the view (on the fly)

Comment: @fusselchen sure

Comment: @fusselchen i have updated with the below code, but not able to solve the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add getter to adapter:

```
public int getSumOfSubjectObtainedMarks(){
    int sum;
    foreach(StudentProgressReportPojo course: student_list_courses){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(course.getSubjectObtainedMarks());
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And then use `studentProgressReportAdapter.getSumOfSubjectObtainedMarks()` to display proper data.

One more thing: fields should be lowercase, so `subjectObtainedMarks` not `SubjectObtainedMarks` etc.

Comment: please let me know it you'll need any more help

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: add an null check or set an init value for your int. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it